# setting the textview on item list select

Tags: android

I am trying to use a dialog to display a list of strings.... then on click of any of the item, I need to set the text in the activity

**`What have i tried ?`**

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void popUp(View v){

        //declare the collection to add people into them
        ArrayList<String> NamesOfPeople=new ArrayList<String>();
        NamesOfPeople.add("USA");//add person
        NamesOfPeople.add("CANADA");//add person
        NamesOfPeople.add("RUSSIA");//add person

        // set the dialog to be displayed on the present activity ... so context is MainActivity.this
        final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.list_of_names);//set the liststructure
        dialog.setTitle("List Of People");// Set the title of the dialog

        //find the listview using id ...remember listview is on dialog now so
        ListView LV=(ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        // Now i need  to put the data from the collection to the listview
        // We shall use an arrayadapter for this
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, NamesOfPeople);
        //we always set the adapter using the listview
        LV.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Dont forget to show the dialog
        dialog.show();

        LV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //dialog.dismiss();// used to cancel the dialog on click of it
                TextView TV=(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView);

                //TV.setText(arg1);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="154dp"
        android:text="SelectString" 
        android:onClick="popUp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
        android:text="NAME"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**list_of_names.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

**Where i am stuck**::

*I am able to show the pop-up dialog, but how to set the text on select of one of the strings from the list*

---

### **{Edit}**

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void popUp(View v){

        //declare the collection to add people into them
        final ArrayList<String> NamesOfPeople=new ArrayList<String>();
        NamesOfPeople.add("USA");//add person
        NamesOfPeople.add("CANADA");//add person
        NamesOfPeople.add("RUSSIA");//add person

        // set the dialog to be displayed on the present activity ... so context is MainActivity.this
        final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.list_of_names);//set the liststructure
        dialog.setTitle("List Of People");// Set the title of the dialog

        //find the listview using id ...remember listview is on dialog now so
        ListView LV=(ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        // Now i need  to put the data from the collection to the listview
        // We shall use an arrayadapter for this
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, NamesOfPeople);
        //we always set the adapter using the listview
        LV.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Dont forget to show the dialog
        dialog.show();

        LV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //dialog.dismiss();// used to cancel the dialog on click of it
                TextView TV=(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView);

                TV.setText(NamesOfPeople.get(arg2).toString());
            }
        });
    }




}
```

**log**

```
12-18 16:41:53.757: E/AndroidRuntime(902): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
12-18 16:41:53.816: E/AndroidRuntime(902): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-18 16:41:53.816: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at com.example.popupofstrings.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:59)
12-18 16:41:53.816: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
12-18 16:41:53.816: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3285)
12-18 16:41:53.816: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1640)
12-18 16:41:53.816: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-18 16:41:53.816: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-18 16:41:53.816: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-18 16:41:53.816: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
12-18 16:41:53.816: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 16:41:53.816: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-18 16:41:53.816: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
12-18 16:41:53.816: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
12-18 16:41:53.816: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-18 16:41:53.836: I/dalvikvm(902): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
12-18 16:41:53.836: E/dalvikvm(902): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple you can use this :

```
LV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //dialog.dismiss();// used to cancel the dialog on click of it
            TextView TV=(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView);

            TV.setText(NamesOfPeople.get(arg2).toString());
        }
    });
```

Remove this

```
 TextView TV=(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

from ***OnItemClickListener*** method and put on onCreate() method

```
 TextView TV=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Comment: Yes...You can access it any where in your class

Answer (score 1):

Try this one...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void popUp(View v){

    //declare the collection to add people into them
    ArrayList<String> NamesOfPeople=new ArrayList<String>();
    NamesOfPeople.add("USA");//add person
    NamesOfPeople.add("CANADA");//add person
    NamesOfPeople.add("RUSSIA");//add person

    // set the dialog to be displayed on the present activity ... so context is MainActivity.this
    final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.list_of_names);//set the liststructure
    dialog.setTitle("List Of People");// Set the title of the dialog

    //find the listview using id ...remember listview is on dialog now so
    ListView LV=(ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.listView);

    // Now i need  to put the data from the collection to the listview
    // We shall use an arrayadapter for this
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, NamesOfPeople);
    //we always set the adapter using the listview
    LV.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Dont forget to show the dialog
    dialog.show();

    LV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //dialog.dismiss();// used to cancel the dialog on click of it
            TextView TV=(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView);
           // add following line
            TV.setText(NamesOfPeople.get(arg2));
            //TV.setText(arg1);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
TextView TV;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   TV=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
}
```

and your item click.

```
LV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            TV.setText(NamesOfPeople.get(arg2).toString());
            //or 
            TV.setText(((TextView) arg1).getText().toString().trim());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to show a set of String in a Dialog box and then to do some action on single option choice will be:

1. First start with declaring an array in `strings.xml` file

   ```
   <string-array name="strings_options">
       <item>String one</item>
       <item>String two</item>
       <item>String three</item>
       <item>String four</item>
   </string-array>
   ```

   We may declare a string array in the `Activity` it self, but defining and declaring it in the `strings.xml` file gives us more control in future when there is need to provide localization support.
2. Now in next step we will simply create an `AlertDialog` with single choice Items i.e. our strings.

   ```
   AlertDialog.Builder = 
       new AlertDialog.Builder(CONTEXT)
          .setTitle("Options")
          .setSingleChoiceItems(R.string.string_options, null,
           new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {
                           switch(position){
                             case 1: break;
                             case 2: break;
                             .
                             .
                             .
                             default:
                             break;
                           }
           });
          .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
          .create().show();
   ```

Comment: Thanks for sharing Good info ! [+1]

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
final CharSequence[] items = {commentshareType, "Facebook", "Twitter", "Email" };

   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);                                   
      builder.setTitle("Share");                                    
      builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {                                       
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,  int item) {

    if (items[item].equals("Delete")) {

   } else if (items[item].equals("Report Abuse")) {

  } else if (items[item].equals("Facebook")) {  

 } else if (items[item].equals("Twitter")) {

    } else if (items[item].equals("Email")) {   

        }                                   
       });

     AlertDialog alert = builder.create();                                  
     alert.show();
```